# angular form validation focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to do a form validation, when input is empty upon submission it should focus on that empty field. I'm looping through the element.class to do .focus() but I don't know how to find which one is empty and to focus on that field.

```
var refocusInput = function() {
            $timeout(function(){
                var inputHasError = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
                for (var i = 0; i < inputHasError.length; i++) {
                    var element = inputHasError[i];
                    if(element){
                        console.log(inputHasError);
                        inputHasError[i].focus();
                        console.log('focus')
                    }
                }
        })
    }
vm.publishForm = function (){
    refocusInput();
}
```

Comment: oh my god, please don't tell that you do this inside of controller...

Answer (score 1):

you are using angular therefore you can always use the `ng-form` attribute and the `$valid` property

*the example is from angular documentation* [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

```js
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('FormController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.userType = 'guest';
      $scope.submit = function(e) {
        $scope.isValid = $scope.myForm.$valid
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```css
.my-form {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  background: transparent;
}
.my-form.not-valid{
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="formExample">

  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" ng-class="{'not-valid' : !isValid}" class="my-form">
    userType:
    <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
    <input type='button' ng-click='submit($event)' value='submit' />
    <br>
    <code>userType = {{userType}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</code>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah already doing that kind of validation but wanted to extend more, but will update this once I found an answer.

Comment: Well what I wanted is when you submit the form only then will trigger an ng-class "error" and focus on specific input where its empty.

Comment: add some changes to make it work like you expected. look at the `$scope.submit` function in the controller